# Blazor Wasm with AAD B2C: SignUpSignIn userflow - reset password, how to catch AADB2C90118

Tags: authentication, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, blazor-webassembly, password-recovery

I am working on a Blazor Wasm app which uses AAD B2C.
The AAD B2C is set up correctly, with different user flows.
The SignUpSignIn has the "Forgot your password" link which is not working out of the box. As I read the app needs to catch the error and trigger the PasswordReset userflow manually.

I try to catch it in the Authorization component, like reading the triggered uri.
It looks like this:

https://localhost:44319/authentication/login-callback#error=access_denied&error_description=AADB2C90118%3a+The+user+has+forgotten+their+password.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+ .... ids and token..

So it contains everything what I need, but the app completely ignores it. I am not able to debug at all.
After some redirects it ends up at: https://localhost:44319/authentication/login-failed page.

I can catch the "login-failed" case, but it is not what I am looking for.

What do you suggest to make it work?

Comment: any luck with this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem! I can't catch the exception or the query parameters from URI (using console, I see that I only get /login-callback#), so I can't understand when redirect to Forgot Password endpoint automatically... I only succeeded in reach the Forgot Password endpoint manually, on simple button click)
https://iheartms.azurewebsites.net/2020/04/10/blazor-aad-b2c-additional-user-flows/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this feature is not supported. Please raise [user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) feedback. This will help the product team evaluates such feature.